# construct calls parent construct

Tags: php

при создании контроллера в laravel появляется вот такой кусочек кода вверху:

```
 public function __construct()
 {
    parent::__construct();
 {
```

как я понимаю, он просто вызывает __construct у контроллера, который экстендится.
Недавно поставил себе штуку для проверки кода, и она жалуется на этот кусок кода, говоря, что он как бы бесполезен, типа конструктор родителя итак вызывается автоматически.

Так ли это? Стоит ли оставить как есть, или лучше убрать подобный код?

Comment: @ArchDemon ваш коммент тянет на полноценный ответ

Comment: Если вы уберёте конструктор в дочернем классе, то конструктор родителя будет вызван автоматически. Т.к. кроме вызова родительского конструктора больше ничего не делается, это можно смело сделать

Comment: @ArchDemon ага понял уже)) спс)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Замечание**: Конструкторы, определенные в классах-родителях не вызываются автоматически, если дочерний класс определяет собственный конструктор. Чтобы вызвать конструктор, объявленный в родительском классе, требуется вызвать `parent::__construct()` внутри конструктора дочернего класса. Если в дочернем классе не определен конструктор, то он может быть унаследован от родительского класса как обычный метод (если он не был определен как приватный).

Источник https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.decon.php